# Two methods that differ only in LINQ where part - delegate?

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, delegates, oop

I have a method:

```
internal List<int> GetOldDoctorsIDs
{
    var Result = from DataRow doctor in DoctorTable.Rows
                 where doctor.Age > 30
                 select doctor.ID
    List<int> Doctors = new List<int>();
    foreach (int id in Result)
    {
         //Register getting data
         Database.LogAccess("GetOldDoctorsID: " + id.ToString());
         if (Database.AllowAccess(DoctorsTable, id))
         {
             Doctors.Add(id);
         }
    }
}
```

So this gets old doctors and does other things. Now I would like to create method GetExpensiveDoctors. It will look like this above, but in place of:

```
where doctor.Age > 30
```

I will have:

```
where doctor.Cost > 30000
```

How to create elegant, object oriented solution for this? 
Should I use delegate or other thing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to do this in this way:

```
internal List<int> GetOldDoctorsIDs()
{
    return GetDoctorsIDs((doctor) => doctor.Age > 30);
}

internal List<int> GetExpensiveDoctorsIDs()
{
    return GetDoctorsIDs((doctor) => doctor.Cost > 30000);
}

internal List<int> GetDoctorsIDs(Func<DataRow, bool> Condition)
{
    var Result = from DataRow doctor in DoctorTable.Rows
                 where Condition(doctor)
                 select doctor.ID
    List<int> Doctors = new List<int>();
    foreach (int id in Result)
    {
         //Register getting data
         Database.LogAccess("GetOldDoctorsID: " + id.ToString());
         if (Database.AllowAccess(DoctorsTable, id))
         {
             Doctors.Add(id);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I suggested as Func<T,TReturn> where TReturn is of type bool is equivalent to Predicate<T>.

Answer (score 3):

If you modify your method so that a predicate parameter is included (see below), you can call the method with any filters you need as per helium's examples.

```
internal List<int> GetDoctorsIDs(Predicate<DataRow> doctorFilter)
{
    var Result = from DataRow doctor in DoctorTable.Rows
                 where doctorFilter(doctor)
                 select doctor.ID
    List<int> Doctors = new List<int>();
    foreach (int id in Result)
    {
         //Register getting data
         Database.LogAccess("GetOldDoctorsID: " + id.ToString());
         if (Database.AllowAccess(DoctorsTable, id))
         {
             Doctors.Add(id);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the where clause selectively, for example:

```
var Result = from DataRow doctor in DoctorTable.Rows
                 select doctor.ID;
if(getByAge) {
    Result=Result.Where(doctor => doctor.Age>30);
} else {
    Result=Result.Where(doctor => doctor.Cost>30000);
}
```

where `getByAge` would be for example a boolean parameter on your method.

**EDIT**. If you need to parametrize the where clause, something like this should work:

```
internal List<int> GetOldDoctorsIDs(Func<Doctor, bool> whereClause)
{
    var Result = DoctorTable.Rows.Where(d => whereClause(d)).Select(d => d.ID);
    //etc...
}
```

then you invoke the method the way helium has said.

Comment: Yes, but what if I will have 6 next methods that change only in where part?

Comment: When I write DoctorTable.Rows. i dont get by Intellisense Where, so it's not there

Comment: And when I do: select DataRow doctor in DoctorTable>Rows where (rows => whereClause(d) select doctor.ID i get error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type bool because it is not a delegate type

Answer (score 0):

You could parameterize your method so it takes the condition as a function from DataRow to bool.

Than you could call

```
GetDoctorsIDs(doctor => doctor.Age > 30);
```

or

```
GetDoctorsIDs(doctor => doctor.Cost > 30000);
```

Comment: Could you be more descriptive about this solution?